# Flash shared object (i.e. flash cookie) is not shared with Chrome

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I wrote a simple swf to set and get shared objects.
When I set data to it through FF and try to get the same object through IE it works fine.
But, when I'm trying to get it through Chrome, it doesn't work - like Chrome has it's own place for the local storage.

I used the below url to see if the shared object is saved: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

I don't work at oovoo, but I see that they have the same issue :)
You can simulate it by browsing to www.oovoo.com in FF and open the below link in IE and Chrome - you will see that oovoo.com shared object only in IE.

Any idea why it happens ?

10x,

Comment: Is your swf embeded from a different domain? Is it third-party?

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this issue as well. It seems Chrome is not using the Shared Objects you would expect it to (**%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\**). Chrome seems to be keeping its own in: **%APPDATA%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot\#SharedObjects\**

I don't know if this is a bug or intentional, but it certainly is annoying.

Comment: This is intentional. Chrome comes with it's own flash plugin. You can change the plugin that Chrome uses by going to: chrome://plugins. Pepper Flash is now apparently the default Flash plugin in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the flash plugin that chrome uses.

If you type: "about:plugins" in your chrome address bar, you can see the plugins that chrome is currently using. If the current enabled flash player is "pepperflash", your shared objects aren't going to be stored.

What you need to do, is download a new version of flash from Adobe's site.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#main_How_do_I_install_the_latest_version_of_Flash_Player_in_Google_Chrome_

After you have a new version of flash, go back into your Chrome plugins, disable the "pepperflash" version of flash, and enable the other one.

After doing this, I've been able to use shared objects just fine with Chrome.